# Bootstrap Navbar collapse "flicking" and issue with 768X1024 resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thanks for reading.... Rarely do I ask the community any questions but I am somewhat lost on this one!

Navbar Collapse is not working on 768X1024 media, Navbar Collapse Button is clicked the function is all jacked up!

link to demo: http://demo.jamessaint.com/redesign-clubgt/index.html

I have gone through my mark-up, and CSS many times but can't find the fault!

Comment: That could be happening because the height of the navigation first changes to proper size 328px, and then instantly switches to height auto. Are you modifying navbar behavior in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 585 of your style.css:

```
.navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

Commenting out `display: none` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks! How on earth did that sneak in there! Just get blind sometimes!